# lodash merge and combine objects

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, lodash

I have an array of objects as below that I read from my database using sequelize ORM: 
I want to have all my videos from a section, but the better I can return using sequelize is :

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ru",
    "subsection": 1,
    "Video": {
      "id": 11,
      "source": "sourrrccrsss22222",
      "videoSubSection": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ru",
    "subsection": 1,
    "Video": {
      "id": 12,
      "source": "sourrrccrsss111",
      "videoSubSection": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oc",
    "subsection": 1,
    "Video": {
      "id": 13,
      "source": "sourrrcc",
      "videoSubSection": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oc",
    "subsection": 1,
    "Video": {
      "id": 14,
      "source": "sourrrcc",
      "videoSubSection": 1
    }
  }]
```

Is there a way to merge and combine the objects in my array to obtain something like this :

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ru",
    "subsection": 1,
    "Video": [{
      "id": 11,
      "source": "sourrrccrsss22222",
      "videoSubSection": 2
    },{
      "id": 12,
      "source": "sourrrccrsss111",
      "videoSubSection": 2
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Oc",
    "subsection": 1,
    "Video": [{
      "id": 13,
      "source": "sourrrcc",
      "videoSubSection": 1
    },{
      "id": 14,
      "source": "sourrrcc",
      "videoSubSection": 1
    }]
  }
```

The function that approach the most is _.mergeWith(object, sources, customizer) but the main problem I have is that I have on object and need to merge this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you can use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with a temporary object for the arrays.

```js
var data = [{ id: 2, name: "Ru", subsection: 1, Video: { id: 11, source: "sourrrccrsss22222", VideoSubSection: 2 } }, { id: 2, name: "Ru", subsection: 1, Video: { id: 12, source: "sourrrccrsss111", VideoSubSection: 2 } }, { id: 1, name: "Oc", subsection: 1, Video: { id: 13, source: "sourrrcc", VideoSubSection: 1 } }, { id: 1, name: "Oc", subsection: 1, Video: { id: 14, source: "sourrrcc", VideoSubSection: 1 } }],
    merged = function (data) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!(a.id in o)) {
                o[a.id] = [];
                r.push({ id: a.id, name: a.name, subsection: a.subsection, Video: o[a.id] });
            }
            o[a.id].push(a.Video);
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(merged, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [transform()](https://lodash.com/docs#transform):

```
_.transform(data, (result, item) => {
  let found;

  if ((found = _.find(result, { id: item.id }))) { 
    found.Video.push(item.Video);
  } else {
    result.push(_.defaults({ Video: [ item.Video ] }, item));
  }
}, []);
```

Using [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) would work here as well, but `transform()` is less verbose.

Comment: I will try when I can, the solution is elegant with few lines.

Comment: Work like perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (`test` is your db output here)

```
var result = [];
var map = [];

_.forEach(test, (o) => {
  var temp = _.clone(o);
  delete o.Video;
  if (!_.some(map, o)) {
    result.push(_.extend(o, {Video: [temp.Video]}));
    map.push(o);
  } else {
    var index = _.findIndex(map, o);
    result[index].Video.push(temp.Video);
  }
});

console.log(result); // outputs what you want.
```